# cannot load such file -- google/apis/sheets_v4 (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

I'm writing an app that accesses and edits google sheets. I have the same code working in a ruby test file, but when I copy the code line for line to the rails model it throws an error: `cannot load such file -- google/apis/sheets_v4 (LoadError)`

I have made sure to require `google/apis/sheets_v4` and that I'm up to date on 'google-api-client' Both of my files are in the same folder, so they should have access to the same libraries.

The only potential source of error that I have so far is that some part of the app relies on a legacy version of `google-api-client`, so both 0.4.7 and 0.23.3 are installed. Is there a way to force utilization of one over the other?

The app was developed before my arrival at the company, so I don't know the reasoning for the use of a legacy api (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution from [this github forum](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/132) to use the version you want:

> I had to do
>
> ```
> gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.7.1'
> ```
>
> then bundle update google-api-client addressable faraday and that let
>   me figure out which other gems to update for me to be able to use that
>   newer gem version. Because of dependencies by default bundle was
>   installing older version for me.

Comment: I tried this method at your suggestion, but got `can't activate google-api-client (= 0.23.3), already activated google-api-client-0.4.7.` It sounds like it can't run multiple versions of the same gem concurrently.